# Is it okay to delete all 'Capcha' Image files?

Tags: captcha

I don't use 'Capcha' feature

and found there are a LOT of capcha image file on ftp

Is there any problem to delete all Capcha image files? or is it okay?

Deleting those files effect any performance?

(Having a lot of useless files in ftp make slow the site little?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you  are not using 'Capcha' feature Disable form admin panel

System->configuration->admin->capcha.

and if you want you can delete the image